# How to use the same output from a random choice

Tags: python

I want to use an output selected randomly from a list, and use that same output again later. How do I have it use the same output given from a random output, rather than giving another random output?

Here is my code currently:

```
print("Good you will have to do two things, first answer my question, second 
guess my number")
speed = int(input("What is the top mph you have reached in the last week?"))
time = ('5','10')
print('You have traveled at' ,speed, 'mph for' ,random.choice(time), 
'hours.' )
distance = int(input('How many miles have you traveled?'))
if distance == speed * int(random.choice(time)):
  print('Good job, now simply guess my number.')
else:
  print("Better luck next time, looks like you don't know your velocity equation")
```

the "int(random.choice(time))" is where I would like to use the same output as that in the print two lines above.

P.S sorry if this is an easy question to ask, it is my first time coding with python.

Comment: This question is fairly broad, as there are lots of ways to solve this but here's a hint, which hopefully lets you solve this on your own: Why do you need to call the `random.choice()` function twice? And is there a way to avoid doing so?

Comment: I'm still lost on how to solve this sorry

Comment: Why don't you store the result of `random.choice` in a variable and just use the variable twice?

Comment: Call `int(random.choice(time))`, save the result into a variable, and use it as many times as you need.

Comment: I did that and it worked thank you all for helping!